How do I convert a string of variables to a binary value in F#?
I am new to F# and have been to trying to do this for quite some time now. So I have a string that looks something "!p & !q & r & !s". I should now convert this to a binary valuee i.e., when it encounters !p, it should output a value 0 and when it encounters p, it should output value 1. Same for q, r and s. So "!p & !q & r & !s" should give me the value 0010 and "p & q & !r & s" should give the value 1101 and so on for all possible combinations. Not sure how I can do this efficiently in F#.
So I tried writing something like this for just one variable but it looks really dumb.
    let app = "(!p)"
    if app.Contains("!p") then printfn "0"
    if app.Contains("p") && app.[app.IndexOf("p")-1] <> '!' then printfn "1"

Edit: This doesn't need any complex parser. It should just be able to read through the string, ignore &,( and blank spaces and print a 0 if a variable is prefixed with ! else 1.

asdadadad asa dad a sd

The question is unclear. There isn't a string of variables, there's a string with something that looks like a boolean expression with a custom syntax. I assume p and q are parameters whose values come from "somewhere". You'll have to create a parser that understands this syntax, parse the string and execute it passing the parameter values

To solve this reasonably generally you can parse the expression into an AST, and then evaluate the AST given the values of the symbols.

If !p & !q & r & !s is supposed to return 0010, it's not even a boolean or bitwise expression, and there's no need for a complex parser. The & character and the actual parameters don't seem to matter, only the existence of !. You can probably create a regular expression (or just string replacements) that ignores whitespace and &, and replaces any word character with 1 or 0 depending on whether they're prefixed with !. If that's the entire grammar, there's no reason for a complex parser

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes that's right. There's no need for a complex parser. I just don't know how it can iterate through the string ignoring whitespace and & operators.

Do you need an 'or' (e.g. ||) operator with the 'and' (&) one?

@Foxy No it just deals with & operator so or can be ignored

First split the string using String.Split with appropriate parameters to ignore the whitespace. Then use String.StartsWith for each part to see if there's an exclamation mark at the start of  the part. Use Array.Map to convert the parts to bools. You can start with the string and just pipe your way to the final result, but using intermediate results to start with can make the exercise easier.

With clarification in the comments that, for single lower case letters s, then need to return:

!s -> 0
s -> 1

and ignore everything else.
I think this is more easily done in two steps, the first to do the above and then the second to remove anything that is not 0 or 1.
So something like
open System.Text.RegularExpressions;

let input = "!p & !q & r & !s"

let passOne = Regex.Replace(input, @"!?[a-z]",
                fun m ->
                    let v = m.Value
                    if v[0] = '!' then
                        "0"
                    else
                        "1"
                )

let passTwo = Regex.Replace(passOne, @"[^01]", "")

printfn "%s" passTwo

The first replace uses one of the overloads for Regex.Replace that takes a MatchEvaluator delegate which is passed a Match object and returns a string and that string is used as the replacement for that match. This makes replacement that depends on the value of the match very much easier.
For production code create static Regex objects and use the instance methods to avoid repeated compilation of the same regex. (Advanced option use a C# project to make use of the regex code generator for maximum regex performance.)

If the string is "simple", as in your example, then a simple manipulation would suffice:
let tokenize (text: string) = text.Replace(" ", "").Split '&'
let eval' (token: string) = if token.StartsWith '!' then 0 else 1
let convert' (text: string) = tokenize text |> Array.map eval' |> String.Concat

let expr = "!p & !q & r & !s"
printfn "%A" (convert' expr)

This code won't work, however, if you allow parentheses (in other words, if you allow 'not' on another boolean expressions in your case), as you need to evaluate them to know whether the result will be 0 or 1.
In order to take this case into account, my approach was to write a small parser using FParsec. We have the following data tree:
type BoolExpr =
    | Variable of char      // a, b, c, ...
    | Not of BoolExpr       // !BoolExpr
    | And of BoolExpr list  // BoolExpr & BoolExpr & ... & BoolExpr

and the following parser:
let boolExpr, impl = createParserForwardedToRef()
let pvariable = [ 'a' .. 'z' ] |> anyOf |>> Variable
let pnot = pipe2 (spaces >>. skipChar '!') (spaces >>. boolExpr) (fun _ expr -> Not expr)
let pand = sepBy1 (spaces >>. boolExpr) (spaces >>. skipChar '&') |>> And
let parens = between (pchar '(') (pchar ')') (spaces >>. pand)
let boolExprImpl = choice [ parens; pvariable; pnot; pand ]
impl.Value <- boolExprImpl

let parse = runParserOnString pand () null

I've considered the general case, i.e. each time I assume the possibility of spaces between tokens (with the spaces combinator) but you can lighten things up if necessary. There's undoubtedly room for improvement, but that's enough for the future. I'll improve it if I have time.
Next, you need a Boolean expression evaluator:
let rec eval =
    function
    | Variable _ -> true
    | Not expr -> not (eval expr)
    | And [ x ] -> eval x
    | And (x :: xs) -> List.fold (fun acc a -> acc && eval a) (eval x) xs

This function simply returns true or false and will be used to check whether the result of a calculation will be displayed as "1" or "0":
let boolToString =
    function
    | true -> "1"
    | false -> "0"

We then define a conversion function, which will take a Boolean expression and return the list of 1's and 0's corresponding to the evaluation of successive and (&):
let rec convert =
    function
    | Variable _ -> "1"
    | Not expr -> boolToString (eval expr)
    | And (xs) ->
        let z = List.map (eval >> boolToString) xs
        System.String.Concat z

Normally, since in the parser I've chosen to use pand as the default parser, which therefore always returns an And in the syntax tree, the first two cases of the convert function will never be encountered as the code has been written, but I'm putting them in anyway for the sake of clarity.
We can test:
let expr1 = "!p & !q & r & !s"
let expr2 = "!p & !q & (x & !i) & r & !s"

let printResult expr =
    match parse expr with
    | Success(result, _, _) ->
        let binary = convert result
        printfn "%s" binary
    | Failure(msg, _, _) ->
        printfn "Parsing error: %s" msg

printResult expr1 // 0010
printResult expr2 // 00010

The final code is:
open System
open FParsec

type BoolExpr =
    | Variable of char
    | Not of BoolExpr
    | And of BoolExpr list

let boolExpr, impl = createParserForwardedToRef()
let pvariable = [ 'a' .. 'z' ] |> anyOf |>> Variable
let pnot = pipe2 (spaces >>. skipChar '!') (spaces >>. boolExpr) (fun _ expr -> Not expr)
let pand = sepBy1 (spaces >>. boolExpr) (spaces >>. skipChar '&') |>> And
let parens = between (pchar '(') (pchar ')') (spaces >>. pand)
let boolExprImpl = choice [ parens; pvariable; pnot; pand ]
impl.Value <- boolExprImpl

let parse = runParserOnString pand () null

let rec eval =
    function
    | Variable _ -> true
    | Not expr -> not (eval expr)
    | And [ x ] -> eval x
    | And (x :: xs) -> List.fold (fun acc a -> acc && eval a) (eval x) xs

let boolToString =
    function
    | true -> "1"
    | false -> "0"

let rec convert =
    function
    | Variable _ -> "1"
    | Not expr -> boolToString (eval expr)
    | And (xs) ->
        let z = List.map (eval >> boolToString) xs
        System.String.Concat z

let expr1 = "!p & !q & r & !s"
let expr2 = "!p & !q & (x & !i) & r & !s"

let printResult expr =
    match parse expr with
    | Success(result, _, _) ->
        let binary = convert result
        printfn "%s" binary
    | Failure(msg, _, _) ->
        printfn "Parsing error: %s" msg

printResult expr1
printResult expr2

I've written this reply "quickly" because I don't have any more time at the moment, so what I'm proposing is certainly improvable, I'll come back to it if I have time.

As the question clearly indicates, this is not a big deal. It's just a simple exercise to get to know the basics of F#. There is no need for advanced tools of any sort, but just a tiny piece of logic. This is how I solved it using LINQPad.
First, just a helper function to use Dump in LINQPad in a more idiomatic manner in F#. Dump is such a great tool, because it displays pretty much anything as is. This is great for exploring what goes on. If you don't use LINQPad, then just leave out lines with dump.
let dump x = x.Dump()

To allow shadowing - that is, reuse of names - let's put the logic in a function named test. Then we'll run that.
let test () =
    let s = "!p & !q & r & !s"
    let a = s.Split('&', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ||| StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
    dump a // a : [| "!p"; "!q"; "r"; "!s" |]
    let a = a |> Array.map (fun s -> not (s.StartsWith '!'))
    dump a // a : [| false; false; true; false |]
    let a = a |> Array.map (fun b -> if b then "1" else "0")
    dump a // a : [| "0"; "0"; "1"; "0" |]
    let s: string = a |> String.concat ""
    printfn "Result: %s" s // 0010
test ()

When using the String.Split function with the given options, the assumption is that there can be multiple spaces anywhere in the string, even in front or after the expression, except between an exclamation mark and the name that follows.
If we were to cope even with multiple spaces between an exclamation mark and the name, then that can easily be solved with a simple function that specifically remove those spaces only. Then this function can be applied before String.Split. But that's not the case now.
The steps in the test function are now ideally set up for piping. So let's clean up the code, using piping. Two steps in the pipe are also combined into one, so there's just one single use of Array.map here.
let [<Literal>] sso = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ||| StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries
let test2 () =
    let result =
        "!p & !q & r & !s".Split('&', sso)
        |> Array.map (fun s -> if s.StartsWith '!' then "0" else "1")
        |> String.concat ""
    printfn "Result: %s" result
test2 ()

